# XML intellisense in C# as in VB.Net?

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, intellisense

Is it possible to enable XML intellisense in a C# class as it is in the VB editor?  Similar to this article's prescriptions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531325.aspx

Would like to not have to use xsd.exe to generate a class from the XML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because C# doesn't support XML literals like VB does in the first place - there's really nowhere in the language where the IntelliSense would pop up, unless it detected that you were calling `Elements` on an `XElement` etc.

Comment: That's a nice feature.  ActionScript has something very similar and it's useful.  This answer provides a way to do something similar in C#, but no intellisense support:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098300/why-isnt-xmldocument-dynamic-in-net-4/3200107#3200107

Answer (score 1):

Not currently - the feature is VB.Net only, commonly called XML Literals.