# Automatic casting of generic List<Entity>

Tags: c#, list, generics, casting, xna

I am building an XNA game with the following simplified structure:

```
class Entity
{
    Vector3 Speed;
    Matrix World;
}

class Mirror : Entity {}

class Lightbeam : Entity {}

class CollisionDetector
{
    /*
    ...
    */

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        List<Entity> entities = entityManager.level.CurrentSection.Entities;

        for (int i = 0; i < entities.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < entities.Count; j++)
            {
                if(entities[i].boundingBox.Intersects(entities[j].boundingBox)) 
                {
                    collisionResponder.Collide(entities[i], entities[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
}

class CollisionResponder
{
    public void Collide(Entity e1, Entity e2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Normal entity collision response");
    }

    public void Collide(Mirror mirror, Lightbeam beam)
    {
        Collide(beam, mirror);
    }

    public void Collide(Lightbeam beam, Mirror mirror)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Specific lightbeam with mirror collision response");
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that the Collide(Lightbeam beam, Mirror mirror) method is invoked when the collision detector detects a collision between a beam and mirror (so entities[i] is a Mirror and entities[j] is a Lightbeam and vice versa). However, since the entities list stores objects of the type Entity, the Collide(Entity e1, Entity e2) method is invoked instead.

What i tried to overcome this problem:

- If a collision is detected, check which types of entities are colliding and invoke the corresponding method. This is quite an ugly solution, since the method should be changed each time a new collision type is added.
- Use generics:
  Collide(Entity e1, Entity e2) 
           where T : Lightbeam
           where U : Mirror

  However, this solution doesn't make the compiler happy.
- I found links to the Builder Pattern and Factory Pattern, but it doesn't seem like        that fixes my problem.

It seems to me that there's a simple solution to this, but I couldn't find any on the internet (using combinations of keywords like the following: generics, subclass, method, overloading, list, automatic casting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the keyword [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx).

**Here is an example:**

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<IEntity> entities = new List<IEntity>();
        entities.Add(new Mirror(1));
        entities.Add(new Mirror(2));
        entities.Add(new LightBeam(1));
        entities.Add(new LightBeam(2));

        //I also fixed your for-loops, you don't need to do entities.Count - 1
        for (int i = 0; i < entities.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < entities.Count; j++)
                Collide((dynamic)entities[i], (dynamic)entities[j]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void Collide(Entity e0, Entity e1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Collision: IEntity {0}[{1}] and IEntity {2}[{3}].", e0.Name, e0.ID, e1.Name, e1.ID);
    }

    public static void Collide(LightBeam lb0, Mirror m0)
    {
        Collide(m0, lb0);
    }
    public static void Collide(Mirror m0, LightBeam lb0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Special Collision: Mirror {0}[{1}] and LightBeam {2}[{3}].", m0.Name, m0.ID, lb0.Name, lb0.ID);
    }
}

//Interfaces are our friends :)
public interface IEntity
{
    String Name { get; }
    Int32 ID { get; }
}

public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    protected Entity(Int32 id = 0)
    {
        ID = id;
    }

    public Int32 ID { get; private set; }
    public abstract String Name { get; }
}

public class Mirror : Entity
{
    public Mirror(Int32 id = 0)
        : base(id)
    {
    }

    public override String Name
    {
        get { return "Mirror"; }
    }
}

public class LightBeam : Entity
{
    public LightBeam(Int32 id = 0)
        : base(id)
    {
    }

    public override String Name
    {
        get { return "LightBeam"; }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Collision: IEntity Mirror[1] and IEntity Mirror[2].
Special Collission: Mirror Mirror[1] and LightBeam LightBeam[1].
Special Collission: Mirror Mirror[1] and LightBeam LightBeam[2].
Special Collission: Mirror Mirror[2] and LightBeam LightBeam[1].
Special Collission: Mirror Mirror[2] and LightBeam LightBeam[2].
Collision: IEntity LightBeam[1] and IEntity LightBeam[2].
```

Comment: This approach assumes the input entities are ordered in the same way as the parameters of the matched method

Comment: @houlgap: Good point. I didn't really take that into consideration. One could always have a combination of methods to account for it. `Collide(Mirror m0, LightBeam lb0) and Collide(LightBeam lb0, Mirror m0)` where one just points to the other. Similar to how the OP points does it. The main issue was that the OP was looking for the proper keyword to account for his situation, which is `dynamic` ;)

Comment: @myermian: Thank you! The dynamic keyword works like a charm! :)
@houlgap: I already thought about that and came up with the same idea myermian just added to his example. It's not that big to maintain this, since collisions can only exist between to entitytypes.

Comment: @Wyste: Just be careful, dynamic is not type-safe. So the compiler will _NOT_ catch typos or other issues you'd catch if the compiler knew exactly what type you were working with :)

Comment: In my opinion, this approach is not really suitable, in general, for game development.

Comment: @Andrew: What's the downfall of using the dynamic keyword in this context? There are tons of uses in which dynamic is an awful approach, but it's only handled dynamically in the call to the Collidemethod of the CollisionResponder. Is it that much more expensive than using a lot of nested loops?

Found these two questions related to this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255982/c-4-real-world-example-of-dynamic-types
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244302/what-do-you-think-of-the-new-c-4-0-dynamic-keyword

Comment: While this is great solution you are still going to need to add an exponential number of Collide methods for each subsequent entity type, unless you are only ever interested if one of those entities is a lightbeam.

Answer (score 1):

CollisionResponder should be an interface with a single method

```
void Collide(Entity e1, Entity e2)
```

Keep a list of these in CollisionDetector, and call each one in turn upon a collision. Within each implementation you can use the "is" operator to check the runtime types and see if you want to do any logic.

The compiler cannot know what the type of the arguments to the functions are at compile time- only a run time check can do what you need.

Comment: That's basically the same solution I stated in my question. It does work, but isn't maintainable when you add let's say 25 other type of entities. With myermian's solution I only have to add two new methods in the CollisionResponder class if I want any new collision logic for other Entity types. Thanks for trying though :)

Comment: @Wytse Are you sure about that? If you had 25 entity types, wouldn't you need 625 functions for collision logic?

Comment: Not all entity types would have special collisions with each other. So that many functions wouldn't be necessary. Then again, wouldn't 625 functions be more elegant than a huge list of if-statements?

Comment: @Andrew: If all combinations needed to be taken into account in your example it would actually require 1250 functions; remember that you have to account for Collide(Foo, Bar) and Collide(Bar, Foo). But,  you'd still have to have those functions. The only difference is that if you do things at compile-time you would use `if-else` and `is` to call the proper function, whereas the `dynamic` keyword would do so at run-time so it's one call. With only 1 or 2 special cases, it is probably more costly (but looks cleaner). With 1250 if-else's I can imagine dynamic is less expensive in some instances.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem here is that you can't know ahead of time whether you are comparing a mirror with a lightbeam, a lightbeam with a mirror, a mirror with a mirror or a lightbeam with a lightbeam. You also suggest that there might be more entity types to be added so that set of possible comparisons begins to swell and as you rightly indicate, all the elements are being addressed as the base Entity anyway.

It would seem that the simplest answer is to separate the lightbeams and mirrors ahead of the comparison loop, then you have a clearly defined relationship for the comparison. You could do this using LINQ but I understand that from a predictable performance aspect this might not be desirable.

If you can't actually hold them separately in your game data structures, you could build two lists thus:

```
List<Entity> entities = entityManager.level.CurrentSection.Entities;
List<Mirror> mirrors = new List<Mirror>();
List<Lightbeam> lightbeams = new List<Lightbeam>();
for (int i = 0; i < entities.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (entities[i] is Mirror)
        mirrors.Add((Mirror)entities[i]);
    if (entities[i] is Lightbeam)
        lightbeams.Add((Lightbeam)entities[i]);
}
```

You loop then becomes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mirrors.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < lightbeams.Count; j++)
    {
        if(mirrors[i].boundingBox.Intersects(lightbeams[j].boundingBox)) 
        {
            collisionResponder.Collide(mirrors[i], lightbeams[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The code will still need updating for each new entity type that's added but your comparisons would be clear. I'd suspect that your split between entity types is likely to be lightbeams and obstacles so I'd still only expect to see two collections as I'd also expect that obstacles couldn't occupy the same bounding box and that would be restricted in the UI. With that in mind, you'd never need to check collision between obstacles beyond the UI, only collision between lightbeam and obstacle. It makes sense (to me anyway) to treat those as layers within the data structures and to maintain them separately.

Comment: That's a solution I hadn't thought about. There are more Entity types to be added indeed. That's why I prefer myermian's solution. Otherwise I wouldn't only have to add the collision logic for any new collisions to the CollisionResponder, but I'd also need to add a new (nested) loop to the CollisionDetector and keep track of all Entity types.

Comment: @Wytse: That is assuming that there are entity types other than obstacles and lightbeams. If we are limited in that way then you are only ever looking for lightbeam->obstacle collisions and the collision code doesn't need to change, no matter how many obstacles you add. Lumping lightbeams and mirrors in together, and me making assumptions over the game type here, seems to be grouping dissimilar objects which, while it may seem appropriate here, could lead to an architecture that causes you more problems down the line.