# What's the use of returning a dynamic in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, language-theory

...compared to plainly returning an object. The magic starts when you **assign** an object to a dynamic declared variable, so what does returning a dynamic  make a difference?

So what is the difference between:

```
static object CreateMagicList()
{
    return new List<string>();
}
```

and

```
static dynamic CreateMagicList()
{
    return new List<string>();
}
```

They both seem to work exactly the same, in example:

```
dynamic list = CreateMagicList();
list.Add( "lolcat" );
```

Note that this is not a practical question. I'm interested in the why part :)

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253460/what-is-the-practical-use-of-dynamic-variable-in-c-sharp-4-0

Comment: Also, you might find this post on MSDN worth a read:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/01/25/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-object-keywords.aspx

Comment: I know the use of a dynamic, read the question please :)

Comment: What about the obvious: CreateMagicList().Add("lolcat"); won't compile if it returns object.

Comment: @user2246674 well sure, but my point is declaring a method to return dynamic means expressions involving just the method are treated as dynamic without the assignment at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you are allowed to return `dynamic` so that you could do this:

```
private static dynamic Get() {
    return new {X=5};
}
public static void Main() {
    var v = Get();
    Console.WriteLine(v.X);
}
```

If you could declare `Get` only as `object Get()`, then your callers would be forced to replace `var` with `dynamic`: otherwise, the code would not compile.

Same goes for a use case without `var`:

```
public static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine(Get().X);
}
```

without `dynamic` return type you would have to do an intermediate assignment, or use a cast to `dynamic`.

Comment: @user2246674 What member variable? No member variables are involved here, only a local variable `v`.

Comment: @user2246674 I cannot think of another thing that you wouldn't be able to do without allowing a `dynamic` return type. I don't think the compiler designers thought specifically about this use case - they allowed it because they could do it, essentially, for free. It was probably cheaper to allow it than to introduce a special case to prohibit use of `dynamic` as method return type.

Comment: That sounds like a fair explanation. It also leads to `Get().X` usage, without an intermediate variable at all, which I think would drive home the difference more.

Answer (score 1):

I think it a point of understanding specific situation in your example it might not make a big difference but it important to consider that dynamic get created at a runtime so you do not have to unbox anything dynamic just take a form of the return type  for instance what if instead of doing this you were required not to bind to dynamic but to list

```
static dynamic CreateMagicList()
{
    return new List<string>();
}

List<string> list = CreateMagicList();
list.Add( "lolcat" );
```

this would work fine since in runtime you bind to same property

but this

```
static object CreateMagicList()
{
    return new List<string>();
}

 List<string> list = CreateMagicList();
    list.Add( "lolcat" );
```

will give you an error since you have to unbox it

Comment: In the example, `dynamic list = CreateMagicList9); list.Add( "lolcat" );` is given - what is the point of having a dynamic return-type vs. having an object return-type and assigning it to a dynamic-typed variable before use?

Comment: as i said it a choice of specific situation

Answer (score 0):

You can return a dynamic, so that in the future, you could actually return a dynamic.  With MissingMethodInvoke and MissingPropertyInvoke overloaded.  Dynamics are more than just objects.